# How to display text using display property in CSS

Tags: php, css

I want to display the text using display property in css

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("amt1").style.display= "none";</script>';
```

I want to display text message instead of `display ="none"` in `amt1` id

Comment: Change display = none to display = block

Answer (score 2):

***1.*** You have to use `.innerHTML` like below:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("amt1").innerHTML= "add your message here";</script>';
```

***2.*** If message is already there and you just want to show that div then change `none` to `block`

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("amt1").style.display= "block";</script>';
```

***3.*** if you want to add message dynamically as well as you want to show the div too, then:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("amt1").innerHTML= "add your message here";
    document.getElementById("amt1").style.display= "block";
    </script>';
```

***Sample javascript code snippet example*** to understand how it will work

```js
document.getElementById("amt1").innerHTML= "This message added in div through javascript .innerHTML method!!!";
document.getElementById("amt1").style.display= "block";
```

```css
#amt1 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="amt1" style="display:none;"></div>
```